# Por que o link para o perfil dos usuários no bate-papo do SOPT não dá preferência para o perfil do SOPT?

Tags: suporte, perfil, chat

Por que no bate-papo, quando eu clico no avatar de algumas pessoas abre uma janela com o texto:

> user profile on stackoverflow.com

ao invés de aparecer o link para o perfil no SOPT?

Por exemplo no meu caso, acho que seria mais lógico se mostrasse meu perfil do SOPT, pois o bate-papo é do SOPT e eu tenho mais reputação no SOPT do que nos outros que participo.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual é a lógica para mostrar o link para o meu perfil do StackOverflow?

Tem como eu configurar o link que aparece nessa janela ou vai ser assim para sempre?

Comment: Não sei se foi só eu que ficou esperando esse negócio mudar sozinho mas foi só eu postar a pergunta que o rubber duck me indicou a direção... Até perguntar não fazia ideia de como configurar isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ele mostra o perfil para o StackOverflow pois esse foi o primeiro site da SE que eu me cadastrei e eu nunca configurei para mudar esse link.

Esse link não muda automaticamente, por eu estar em um bate-papo diferente ou por ter ganho mais reputação em outro site da rede.

Para mudar, basta clicar em `user profile`, logo acima do link do `user profile on stackoverflow.com`, ele te levará para a página do seu perfil do bate-papo, lá é possível mudar o link do perfil para o que preferir. Basta clicar em `change` para a opção `parent user` e escolher o perfil que preferir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fiz como disseste e não me aparece o raio da lista.

Comment: @JorgeB. tem que clicar em `user profile` do seu perfil, não do meu, ok?

Comment: A sério @Math? :P Claro que estou a fazer isso...

Comment: @JorgeB. hahaha.. é que eu pus a foto do meu na resposta, vai saber, rs.. Mas sério, não apareceu nada até agora? Já tentei aqui de novo e foi sem problemas :/

Comment: Não me aparece aquela lista @Math

Comment: @JorgeB. mas comece a digitar "stack" ou "port" que daí aparecem as opções que correspondem aos seus critérios de busca

Comment: foi o que fiz, não aparece nada escreva eu o que escrever...

Comment: @JorgeB. oh crap! Que navegaor usa? Não tá com problema de firewall impedindo JS de carregar ou coisa do tipo? O `select site` aparece né? Pois se não aparecer é porque não está logado na página do perfil do bate-papo. Edição: é claro que está aparecendo, pois já me disse que está digitando.

Comment: Firefox, não tenho problema desses...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19618/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-math).

Comment: Não funciona de forma nenhuma aqui...

Answer (score 0):

No meu não funciona, alguém sabe porque? É preciso ter certo tipo de reputação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Não @Math não consegui resolver.

Comment: O problema é antigo, mas chegou numa conclusão? À época você tinha perfil em quantos sites da rede? Suponho que pra poder mudar seja preciso ter perfil mais de um :)

Comment: @Bacco resolvi, entretanto esqueci-me que tinha isto aqui. Era [este script](http://stackapps.com/questions/4921/turbocharged-help-menu) que estava a bloquear, não me dei ao trabalho de ver porquê, só desabilitei o script.