# Problema com seleção de parent user

Tags: bug, status-pronto, chat, contas-usuário

Ando com este problema quase desde que cheguei ao site e nunca foi resolvido.

Vendo esta pergunta [Por que o link para o perfil dos usuários no bate-papo do SOPT não dá preferência para o perfil do SOPT?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2342/por-que-o-link-para-o-perfil-dos-usu%C3%A1rios-no-bate-papo-do-sopt-n%C3%A3o-d%C3%A1-prefer%C3%AAnci) vi que o @Math consegue escolher.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Experimentei em vários *browser's*.
Será bug?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Fui ver agora o console do browser e apareceu isto:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Tentou digitar `pt.st...`? Sempre uso isso, e sempre vem o SOpt como primeira opção.

Comment: Sim tentei @bfavaretto. A mim não aparece nenhuma opção.

Comment: Troquei o "parent user" pra você.

Comment: Obrigado :) De qualquer forma não devia ser corrigido isso @bfavaretto?

Comment: Sim. Como você marcou com a tag [bug], os devs do site irão olhar a pergunta e procurar a causa. Eu mesmo não consegui reproduzir.

Comment: @Gabe nada ainda?

Comment: Jorge, você tem algum complemento ou cois do tipo que interfere no javascript do navegador? Notei que ao usar a ferramenta de debug do Chrome (Inspecionar Elemento) o buscador para de funcionar e outras coisas também.

Comment: @Molx Não tenho nada. Alias já experimentei com o firefox acabado de instalar.

Comment: Você pode olhar a aba "network" do debugger do Chrome? O erro que você postou diz que o objeto `StackExchange` não está definido. Pode ser que um dos arquivos js não esteja carregando corretamente.

Comment: @bfavaretto carrega tudo direitinho.

Comment: esta devia ser marcada com a tag [tag:status-não-quermos-saber]...

Comment: É difícil achar a causa porque só acontece com você. :(

Comment: Could be a proxy cached a corrupt JavaScript file, which is being served to you. You can try a hard refresh of the page (`Ctrl + F5`), clearing your browser cache (just for chat should be enough). The issue is that some JavaScript isn't running properly - those errors you see shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Oded this is the error that occurs when I search. http://i.imgur.com/wLcuCKX.png

Comment: Very strange. This is when trying to use chat? Can you try accessing with https?

Comment: No, it is when I trying to change new site to my chat profile. With https: http://i.imgur.com/oIDjf5y.png

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? I can't see where the call to jquery.ui is coming from - that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @Oded Firefox/Chrome (same result) UBUNTU 14.04 LTS. The image with the link: http://i.imgur.com/5xIfdYr.png

Comment: @Oded do you have any idea of what will be?

Answer (score 1):

Desde que fui nomeado moderador no [Portuguese Language](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com) que o problema desapareceu, agora funciona direito.

Comment: Solução para os próximos casos similares: Se torne um moderador! :)